# Are there any specific technical requirements/guide for Windows Classic Desktop application?

Tags: windows, desktop-application

I wonder if there are any specific technical (not UI ones, they could be easily found) requirements for Windows Classical desktop applications, e.g. where to store application temporary or persistent data, which registry keys to write and so on.

I tried to google such requirements but had no luck (maybe my 'google' is not so good at all).

Comment: To downvoters: instead of silently downvoting, you could justify your downvote or provide me with some help. Otherwise it's not very useful as far as I still can't find any info on the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so finally I've managed to get some info on the topic.
There is a programme called "Windows Certification" which contains guides and requirements as well as test utilities.
More info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt637086(v=vs.85).aspx